# Linux kernel thread dependency graph?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, threads

I'm trying to benchmark a system with a software RAID-10 volume, backed by Fusion IO cards.  Is it possible to display a Linux kernel thread dependency graph?

I would like to know how all the `[xfs]`, `[md]`, `[md0_raid10]`, and `[fct-smp]` threads communicate and if any are presenting a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have a look on [SystemTap Flamegraph](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2012/03/17/linux-kernel-performance-flame-graphs/)

It uses systemtap to get the data, and a perl script to create the graphs and dig into the syscalls of your application.

There is many more to share, but you should narrow your needs :)

Comment: Wow, those flame graphs are very neat.  Thanks for the suggestion.